# Can't access default gateway of otherwise functional router

Tags: router

A few weeks back I picked up a router from someone who was cleaning out their attic: a Thomson TG789ivn. It was brand new in the box and never used, and it was better than what I have at the moment, so I tried setting it up. plugging it in, it booted up fine, the wifi showed up in my networks, and I could log in using the codes on the sticker on the back. 
I couldn't get an internet connection however, so I figured I'd take a look into the settings screen. Ran ipconfig, got the default gateway (192.168.2.254) and tried to go there, but I got a connection timeout. Tried it a few more times, but no success. I googled around for a few other common gateways for this model, but none of them worked. The strange thing is that a function of the router that hosts the default gateway at a mock web address http://dsldevice.lan did redirect me to the correct gateway, so it does pick up on that. Again, though, connection timed out. Pinging 192.168.2.254 works fine and I get perfect returns, but still no dice, connection timeout whenever I attempt to log in. Across multiple browsers on every system I have on the network, connection timeout.

I'm at a complete and utter loss, about to conclude it is simply broken and throw it out. Does anyone have a clue as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem. My internet was working fine but not able to open my router page(192.168.1.1). After lot of research I found this link [[Fixed]Unable to Open 192.168.1.1 Router Configuration Web Page](http://[Fixed]Unable%20to%20Open%20192.168.1.1%20Router%20Configuration%20Web%20Page) which mentioned few causes of this problem. In mine case it was firewall. After turning off the firewall,my problem was solved.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Even while links still work, the content can't be indexed to help people find the solutions, and the site's concept is to have answers here rather than redirect people elsewhere.  In this case, your link appears to have a problem and doesn't seem to be a properly formed URL.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading. Thanks.